# Prepared statement with subselect using Clojure/Korma/Postgres

Tags: postgresql, clojure, korma

I've been trying to do the following in Korma to no avail:

**sql:**

```
PREPARE q (int) AS SELECT * FROM post a
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT parent_id
         FROM post_map 
         WHERE parent_id=a.id AND parent_id=$1);
EXECUTE q(1);
```

**my best Korma attempt:**

```
(defn children [parent-id]        ;; clojure
      (if (number? parent-id)
        (exec-raw (str
          "PREPARE q (int) AS SELECT * FROM post a WHERE EXISTS 
               (SELECT parent_id FROM post_map WHERE parent_id=a.id AND parent_id=$1); 
           EXECUTE q(" parent-id ")") 
         :results)))
```

**And this is the error I keep getting:** *(I don't really understand the `::` operator below:)*

```
Failure to execute query with SQL:
PREPARE q (int) AS SELECT * FROM post a WHERE EXISTS 
          (SELECT parent_id FROM post_map WHERE parent_id=a.id AND parent_id=$1); 
       EXECUTE q(1)  ::  nil
PSQLException:
 Message: No results were returned by the query.
 SQLState: 02000
 Error Code: 0
PSQLException No results were returned by the query.  org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery (AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:274)
```

I don't think this is a terribly outlandish thing to want to do with a query, so I'm wondering if Korma just isn't going to work for my project. Am I just doing it wrong?

**UPDATE:** this is what I ended up doing (after I bailed on Korma [sorry Korma]).

```
(defn children [parent-id]
  (if (unsigned? parent-id)
    (sql/with-connection db
      (sql/with-query-results results
         [(str "select " field-list ", b.parent_id from post a, post_map b where a.id=b.child_id and a.id in "
               "(select child_id from post c, post_map d where c.id=d.parent_id and c.id=?)") parent-id]
           (into [] results)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Korma uses do-prepared under the hood, which only works for a single statement and also prepares it for you.

This works:

```
;; but isn't it more 'parent' than 'children'?
(defn children-raw [parent-id]
  (if (number? parent-id)
    (exec-raw [(str
                "SELECT * FROM post a WHERE EXISTS
               (SELECT parent_id FROM post_map WHERE parent_id=a.id AND parent_id=?)")
               [parent-id]]
              :results)))
```

I'm slightly confused by your naming/schema, though, even if it is hard to tell from this small example. Your function is called "childREN" but with the EXISTS() I think it will return max a single record. Also, it seems to select the *parent*, but with the implicit join it will always select itself?

If post_map is a link from id to parent_id and you want to get the children, I would think more along the lines of:

```
(defentity post
  (entity-fields :id))
(defentity post_map
  (entity-fields :id :parent_id))
(defn children-dsl [parent-id]
  (if (number? parent-id)
    (select post
            (where {:id [in (subselect post_map
                                       (fields :id)
                                       (where {:parent_id parent-id}))]}))))
```

Comment: Yeah, my query was messed up to begin with (which wasn't really what I was focusing on when I asked this question), but I didn't recognize that until I switched away from korma and back to the jdbc api. I feel like the difference in the level of effort and lines of code between them is negligible and I just wasn't finding Korma intuitive/flexible enough.